# apache is not working after upgrade to 2.4.7

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I use Ubuntu 13.10 for my home system. Today I upgraded apache from version 2.4.6 to version 2.4.7 and it stopped working. By this I mean the following:

Apache is running (I checked with `pgrep apache` and it has the following version `2.4.7-1+sury.org~saucy+1`). When I try to access `http://localhost/` I get

> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

The same thing when I try `http://localhost/index.html`

> The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

I cleaned my `/var/www` folder (removed everything and the only thing that is left is `index.html` which has just one world inside). I also checked that apache has permissions to read the file (in fact I put 777 for all www directory and everything inside just to be sure).

I truncated `error.log` and `access.log` and tried to access localhost once again. Error.log has not changed and the only line :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [TIMESTAMP] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

appeared in access.log.

I am out of ideas what else can I try. Any idea how can I fix this? Another relevant thing is that when I was upgrading apache, it asked me if I want to change my conf file with the new one and I decided to stick with mine (I regret this right now).

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your virtual host configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for looking into the problem. Booteille's answer solved it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue and I just changed the following line in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

by

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Comment: If it worked with that path prior to the upgrade there's no reason it should require changing after the upgrade - So is Ubuntu changing their configuration file, or is something else going on here?

Comment: I think the Ubuntu update has changed the config file here to /var/www/html. I had this same problem after an update. Thanks.

Comment: I am 100% positive that @anjanesh is correct.  Why do they have to mess with things?  Just to give IT job security, I guess...